# Hook menu url giving access denied for post method but working for get method

Tags: 7

I defined a custom url using hook_menu and a custom delivery callback that returns json output.

I wanted the url to work on the post method but it is giving access denied for requests done using the post method but it is working without issues for get method.

How do I debug and see why post methods are being denied access?

```
/**
 * @file
 * Implements menu functions for returning json output.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['api/json/select/programs'] = array(
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_api_return_aid_program',
    'delivery callback' => 'mymodule_api_json_output_wrapper',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
 return $items;
}

/**
 * Custom page callback function - Retuns the uid of the user on passing
 * valid username and passowrd returns error otherwise
 *
 * @return $uid
 *   Uid of the user on success, NULL if other wise
 *
 * @return $status
 *   success of the user on success, failure if otherwise
 */
function mymodule_api_return_aid_program() {
  try {

    // Fetching the primary parameters 
    //product code
    $product = $_POST['product'];
    //country code
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    // language code
    $language = $_POST['language'];


    // age
    //citizenship
    // veteran_status
    $values = _find_product_specific_to_country($product, $country);


    return array('message' => array('nodes' => $values));
  }
  catch(Exception$e) {
    return array('status' => FALSE, 'message' => $e);
    watchdog('Aid API ERROR', $e);
  }
}

/**
 * Custom delivery callback function
 *
 * @param $var
 *   The argument to the delivery callback function
 *
 * @return array
 *   Contains json encoded format of $var on succes,
 */
function mymodule_api_json_output_wrapper($var) {
  // If the access callback is FALSE
  // it will pass MENU ACCESS DENIED to the
  // delivery callback function
    //return drupal_json_output($var);
  if ($var == MENU_ACCESS_DENIED) {

    return drupal_json_output(array('status' => FALSE, 'message' => 'Invalid Token. Access Denied'));
  }
  else {
    return drupal_json_output($var);
  }
}
e
```

Comment: Can you please post your current code?

Comment: Do you have the [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module enabled?

Comment: It was the security kit module that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code works for me:
[image]
Try to move watchdog before return if there is any exception, will log into your report log.
Change your function to like this:

```
function mymodule_api_return_aid_program() {
  try {
    // Fetching the primary parameters
    //product code
    $product = $_POST['product'];
    //country code
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    // language code
    $language = $_POST['language'];
    // age
    //citizenship
    // veteran_status
    $values = _find_product_specific_to_country($product, $country);
    return array('message' => array('nodes' => $values));
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    watchdog('mymodule', 'Aid API ERROR ' . $e->getMessage(), array(), WATCHDOG_NOTICE, NULL);
    return array('status' => FALSE, 'message' => $e->getMessage());
  }
}
```

**Update: debug**
Getting `access denied` maybe another module add/alter your menu and add another `access arguments` then `access content` so in your callback function print you menu object and see something like :

```
  $menu_item = menu_get_item('api/json/select/programs');
  // print the menu array
  print_r($menu_item);
  // Print access arguments
  print_r($menu_item['access_arguments']);
  // Print access callback
  print_r($menu_item['access_callback']);
```

Comment: Its the delivery call back that checks for access denied errors. The $var parameter is getting 3 which is simply saying that the menu is denied. I know the code works but for this particular site it is not working. Need a way to debug.

Comment: Check the update, try to print the menu object in your request, if it gives you `acces denied` page put `die;` after `print_r` good luck.

Comment: Will check and get back

Comment: I took your advice and enabled watchdog and paid close attention to the messages. It seems that the Security module is the culprit. It is terming the requests as a security violation and giving access denied errors.  The message in dblog is as follows. Possible CSRF attack was blocked. IP address: 192.168.89.98, Origin: chrome-extension://aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm. Disabling the module is allowing post requests.

Answer (score -1):

You need to setup a REST API endpoint and assign/authorize it to use the POST API calls. the `/api` should be setup as a REST API endpoint on your website first.
Follow [this guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/2424977) on how to use the [Services module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services).

Update: Do not forget to use the CSRF token with a POST request. Check the guide above for more details on how to obtain that.